# transform the equation in the respective region to canonical form: $u_{xx} + u_{xy} - xu_{yy} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

Here what i did:
$$a=1 ,\quad b=1,\quad c=-x$$
$$\Delta = 1 + 4x$$
$$x < -\frac{1}{4} \rightarrow eliptic$$
$$x = -\frac{1}{4} \rightarrow parabolic$$
$$x > -\frac{1}{4} \rightarrow hyperbolic$$
Characteristic equations:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}= \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4x} }{2}$$
$$\rightarrow y = \frac{x}{2}  + \frac{1}{2}( \frac{(4x+1)^\frac{5}{2})}{40}-\frac{(4x+1)^\frac{3}{2})}{24}) + C_1$$
$$y = \frac{x}{2}  - \frac{1}{2}( \frac{(4x+1)^\frac{5}{2})}{40}-\frac{(4x+1)^\frac{3}{2})}{24}) + C_2$$
I’m stuck here and don’t know what to do next. I think with this result, the next steps will be very difficult and complicated. So, I want to ask if there is a better way to do this and if I made a mistake at any step? I look forward to receiving answers and hints from everyone. Thank you all very much